# Filter columns based on values in row without transposing

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table of the following format.

[image]

I want to filter the columns to only include those with a "B" in the first row. However, due to the restraints on the max number of columns I am unable to transpose the table then filter. This is my desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Promote header
2. [Table.SelectColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectcolumns)
3. Demote header

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(
    Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Select Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(
    #"Promoted Headers",
    List.FindText(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), "B")
),
#"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Select Columns")
```

Comment: The issue with this is that my promoted column headers would be of the form: A_1,A_2, B_3,B_4,B_5 so I cannot filter out "B"

Comment: But you can filter out all those containing a "B" with `Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers",List.FindText(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), "B"))`

Comment: I think your "desired output" doesn't make much sense for further processing anyway. However, I'm transposing huge tables without major performance losses.